# Named scopes for Embedded Document type in MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongomapper

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 with the latest MongoMapper, and I've switched a top level model from being a `MongoMapper::Document` to being a `MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument`.

Suddenly I got an error on the converted class:

*undefined method `scope'*

It seems like named scopes in MongoMapper are only available to top level documents.

I was hoping to use them like such:

```
my_top_level_document.embedded_items.some_named_scope
```

Aside from writing my own block iterator methods, anything straightforward folks do to solve this limitation?